# Checkbox Reference Value in LibreOffice Base Form

Tags: forms, checkbox, reference, boolean, libreoffice-base

I want to make a checkbox in the form editor of Base to fill boolean values (in this case, "Male", and "Female") in my table.

I am currently stuck in the checkbox control window's "Data" tab because I do not know what to put in the fields "Reference value (on)" and "Reference value (off)".

I know that in the table design view that Base refers to the boolean TRUE/FALSE values as "Yes" and "No". Should I use Yes and No as reference values? Should I go TRUE and FALSE? Or 1 and 0? I can just assign arbitrary designations for male and female if I know what to put in the reference value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tested it by trial and error. One apparently has to use TRUE and FALSE as the reference values, otherwise, Base will not fill the boolean checkbox in the table even if you've filled it in the form.